# Resume background App

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

Scenario:
App is in the background, main Activity is in onStop state. I receive a specific message, display a notification to the user, he clicks on it and I want to bring the app to the forwground and just resume the main Activity, without starting a new one.
I want the samw effect as you get when you click on a paused app in the recent tasks(it just resumes).

I assume that this has to do with setting the right flags on an Intent, but I couldn't find it.
Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Notification` just needs to contain a launch `Intent` to bring your app to the foreground in whatever state it was in:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, launchIntent, 0);
```

Set `pi` as `contentIntent` on the `Notification`.